# High-Current Shutoff Protection on a Robot

Tags: batteries, current, dc-motor

I'm working on a robot that uses a total of four motors for its movement. Each are rated for 2A stall, and the battery has a high enough discharge capability to run all of them at full, and then some. However, when going from zero to full in moments the current draw is momentarily so massive that it overwhelms the battery and the voltage drops below the cutoff of the power circuitry (which safely shuts off the robot if the voltage drops below 3V). The entire robot runs off a 12V/5V configuration, with 12V being the maximum voltage it should ever run on.

I was wondering if I could place an array of capacitors (or just one big one) along the feed from the battery to the power distributor to help the battery handle the momentary excessive current draw. **Will this work? Do I need to add an inductor with the capacitor(s)? Or do the capacitor(s) need to be in a different place?**

Using different motors, power distribution system, battery, or control unit is not an option.

Comment: Draw schematic. Add capacitors. Limit maximum accelleration.

Comment: I can add a schematic later. Limiting acceleration is impractical in this robot’s application.

Comment: ^^ "Limit maximum acceleration" being key here.

Comment: You will probable need a lot of caps. You could look at supercaps.

Comment: Could be easier to put a diode in series with the power line to the control circuity and a smaller cap there, so the motors droop the battery all they want, controls keep running. Just need to find out how long the battery will stay under voltage for.

Comment: Problem is @TimMottram that if I bypass the power distribution circuitry at all, the robot becomes “illegal”

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, all your doing is preventing the momentary power supply glitch from switching off the controls. Why does that make it illegal?